# Writing to a file and loading content / suggestions-like

Tags: php, forms, post, fwrite

I have the code to a simple form page. It writes to a file and loads the content with include() but it doesn't work. Any of you could tell me where am I mistaken?

- The **error** is that it doesn't write down to the file anything at all, the form submits and nothing happens.
- I have administrator rights (this happens in local AND hosting).
- Tested the include() and works perfectly.

Sorry for the lack of details. :(

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['msg'])) {

    $msgfile= 'msg.html';
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];
    $msgdetails =  '<p><span>'. date("F j, Y, g:i a") .'</span>: '. $msg .'<br>\n';
    $fp = fopen($msgfile, "a"); 
    fwrite($fp, $msgdetails);
    fclose($fp); 

}

?>

<form method="post" action="#">

    <table>
        <tr><td><h3>Messages</h3></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="msg">
                <input type="submit" value="Add message!">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><?php include('msg.html'); ?></td></tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

Well the error was in the , the NAME param was missing (as mentioned below). Thank you! :)

Comment: I would at least use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting that `$msg` to prevent XSS. And *what* doesn't work? The opening of the file? Writing to it? Including it in your markup?

Comment: Yet another `it doesn't work` type, without reading the manual where it tells you what `include`does..

Comment: Do you have permission to write to `msg.html`?

Comment: Doesn't work how? doesn't write the contents? file stays blank? wrong contents written?

Comment: I am sorry. ok?
Now, It doesn't write down to the file, THAT is the error (but without anything poping up). The include works 100% fine, tested it.
ANd the privileges, YES I have, both the machine and I. I am testing it with local (Wamp) and HOST, and both are failing.

Comment: I noticed that you don't have a 'name="msg"' attribute on your text input -- just an id.

Comment: And `\n` isn't interpreted when using single quotes.

Comment: name attribute was missing, both right. Thank you!!
About the \n, note taken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a name field in

```
 <input type="text" id="msg" name="msg" />
```

rest of your code works fine.  $_POST['msg'] reads the submitted name not the ID